# How to copy 1000+ files to 10 different folders depending on last digit in file name?

Tags: batch-file

I am new on this group and new for scripting. So I hope to make it easy for all of the members.

I need to create a simple script/batch file that makes this:

- Create folder 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
- Copy files from source folder to the new folders just created.

I have one folder which has 1000 PDF files, each file name is a telephone number.

I like to create a batch/script file that make a copy for all the numbers that end with 1 to folder 1, all the files that end with 2 to 2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /l %%a in (0 1 9) do xcopy "c:\source\*%%a.pdf" "c:\target\%%a" /i /y
```

For the digits 0 to 9, copy the pdf files with a file name ending in each digit to the indicated folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested.

```
@echo off

set phones_dir=c:\phones
set destination_parent_dir=c:\parent

if not exist "%destination_parent_dir%" md "%destination_parent_dir%"


pushd "%phones_dir%"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for %%n in (1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;0) do (
    md "%destination_parent_dir%\%%a" 2>nul
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /a:-d *%%a.pdf') do (
        copy /y  "%%~ff" "%destination_parent_dir%\%%a"
    )
)
```